# How to create a gallery custom field for WordPress post?

Tags: custom-field, gallery

I would like to create a custom field for WP posts that behaves like a Gallery Block (I can upload or choose photos from Media Library, and save data to this field).
So that, on the frontend (in the `single` post) I can get a list of photos (from data of the field) and then render them with my own HTML markup.

How to do that?

I am new to WordPress, any helps, advises or practices is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use ACF plugin. Plugin has all the ability to add image type field like you want.

Comment: Yes, I have try using ACF, but the option for Gallery is only available on Pro version.

Comment: You can try this free addon of ACF for gallery. https://wordpress.org/plugins/navz-photo-gallery/